# Python beginner -- change shape of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following img object

```
img.shape = (480,640,3)
```

How do I make `img` just `(480,640)` (i.e. lose the `,3`)?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to do. That's not just a reshaping; your new array would have 1/3 the elements of the old one.

Comment: you just want to understand how to slice tuples?  Or are you using `numpy`?

Comment: Could you tag the question with the libraries you're using?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, I want to drop the size by one third

Comment: `img.shape = img.shape[:2]` (everything up to, but excluding, the 2-th element)

Comment: @user1775603 Tried that. Got "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged"

Comment: What do you want the elements of the new `img` to be? You can't fit all the old ones in there.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't care what happens to the top 2/3. I just want the first third.

Comment: @Eamorr If you're not allowed to change the size of that array in numpy (not that I would know anything about numpy), save it to something else. `truncated_shape = img.shape[:2]`. That is numpy complaining about you trying to change something that shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @2rs2ts `img[...,0]` does the trick

Comment: @Eamorr I'm absolutely bewildered by that syntax. Never seen it before. Perhaps `img.shape` is not a member of `img` at all?

Comment: @2rs2ts: `...` is the `Ellipsis` object. Python 3 lets you use the syntax anywhere, though Python 2 only allows it in extended slicing. Numpy interprets it as "as many colons as necessary" in multidimensional array slicing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first third, you want

```
newimg = img[..., 0]
```

If you'll never need the other two thirds again, but you'll be keeping the first third around for a while, you may want

```
img = img[..., 0].copy()
```

so you don't keep the other parts of the array around.

Comment: OP wants the first two-thirds. `img.shape[0:2]` or `img.shape[:2]` or `img.shape[:-1]` if you want to talk about dropping the last element. You also have to do `.shape` since that is the tuple.

Comment: I tried img[:-1] and when I did `img.shape`, I got (479, 640, 3)

Comment: I meant `img.shape[:-1]` or the ilk - I typed the wrong thing at first and then edited my post.